# How to set popup window style for responsive UI in android

Tags: android, xml, styles, popupwindow

In My android app, I used popup window. 
There is one issue regarding popup window.
In bigger device (height or width) It will show clearly and automatically set margin left or right.
In smaller device like nexus one , Popup window stick with device not set margin left or right.

Or another issue is that In lollipop or marshmallow there is one button look like floating button. You can view in screen shot which I attached below.

That button look good in marshmallow or higher version. 
But in kitkat there is only look like a simple arrow how to resolved it.

Here i specified My popup window source code or screenshots of kitkat device UI and Marshmallow UI.

please any one let me know how to resolved it. In advance, Thank you for your support.

raw_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/demo"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="16dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMainHeading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="@string/headertext"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/popupsubtext"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/viewMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtText"
    android:background="@color/bg_border" />


<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LayoutDetail"
    android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@color/bg_border" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LayoutDetail1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLastNameText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/puplastname"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="15sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLastName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:text="@string/txtLastnametext"
        android:textColor="@color/button_text_dialog"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LayoutDetail1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@color/bg_border" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LayoutDetail2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEmailText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/pupEmail"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="15sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/txtemailtext"
        android:textColor="@color/button_text_dialog"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LayoutDetail2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@color/bg_border" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btnNext"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LayoutDetail2"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_oval"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_icon_right_1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LayoutDetail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtText"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFirstNameText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/pupfirstname"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="15sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFirstName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:text="@string/txtFirstnametext"
        android:textColor="@color/button_text_dialog"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Popupwindow.java

```
private Context mContext;
private Activity mActivity;
private android.widget.PopupWindow mPopupWindow;
private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_countrycode);


    mContext = getApplicationContext();


    // Get the activity
    mActivity = CountrycodeActivity.this;

    // Get the widgets reference from XML layout
    mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mRelativeLayout);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // Inflate the custom layout/view
    View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_layout, null);

    mPopupWindow = new android.widget.PopupWindow(
            customView,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    //    mPopupWindow.setContentView(findViewById(R.id.activity_view_pager));
    mPopupWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.PopupAnimation);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        mPopupWindow.setElevation(24f);
    }

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            mPopupWindow.showAtLocation(mRelativeLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        }

    }, 100L);

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mPopupWindow.dismiss();
}
```

Screenshots of UI

[In marshmallow as well as bigger device nexus 5.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO8lz.png)

[In nexus one as well as kitkat device or smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJB8M.png)

Comment: please provide your xml also

Comment: please view my edited post @SunishaSindhu

Comment: give margin to Relative layout

Comment: Not working :( @SunishaSindhu

Answer (score -1):

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

set RelativeLayout width property fill_parent